# C# process restart loop

Tags: c#, process, restart

I'm trying to make a console app that would monitor some process and restart it if it exits.
So, the console app is always on, it's only job is to restart some other process.

I posted my code below.. it basically works but just for one process restart...

I would appreciate any help!!

Thanks in advance!

```
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(SOME_PROCESS);
        p[0].Exited += new EventHandler(Startup_Exited);

        while (!p[0].HasExited)
        {
            p[0].WaitForExit();
        }

        //Application.Run();
    }

    private static void Startup_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(AGAIN_THAT_SAME_PROCESS);  
    }
```

Comment: If possible, you should consider running the other process as a service. The service control manager in Windows already has functionality to restart a process that terminates abnormally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop, and at the top of the loop you need to reattach `p` to the new process after restarting the program.  So something like:

```
Process p = /* get the current instance of the program */;
while (true)
{
  p.WaitForExit();
  p = Process.Start(/* the program */);
}
```

Note that since Process.Start returns the Process object for the new instance, you don't actually need to re-perform the search: you can just wait directly on the new Process object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet that, upon starting your process again, you need to update the process that p[0] is pointing to and reattach your event handler. It appears that once it dies, your event fires and you never have an event handler registered with a process again.