# Looping a Background Worker Task

Tags: c#

I have some code inside a background worker `DoWork` event which check if a process is running or not. The code in the `DoWork` does the following:
-> If the process is not running, check again twice
-> If the process is running, check if it is responding
-> If the process is running and respoding, do nothing
-> If the process is running and not responding, restart the process

```
 void bgworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int numberTrials = 0;
            bool isNotRunning = false;
            while (isNotRunning = (someProcess.Length == 0) && numberTrials < 3)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("numTrial = {0}", numberTrials.ToString()));
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                ++numberTrials;
            }
            if (isNotRunning)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Start Task");
                someProcess.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                if(!someProcess.IsKioskResponding)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Kill Task");
                }
            }
        }
```

The above thing runs fine but I have to loop the above `DoWork` task for every 3 minutes. Would it be a good thing to keep the above looping task in a timer that has an interval of 3 minutes? (In that way I would have to take care of `Thread.Sleep x numberTrials` not to exceed the Timer's interval). Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you also had a look at the [Process.WaitForExit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)

It is explained with an example here: [process restart loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466767/c-sharp-process-restart-loop)